# How to fill string with required character

Tags: .net, string, .net-3.5, .net-4.0

I need to get string with 8 '*' symbols. How can I do that in .NET 3.5? .NET 4.0?

Thanks.

Comment: I used 8 just as an example, actually I need length to be specified. Reinderien answer works good for me, but system doesn't allow me to accept any answer for 5 minutes yet

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try:

```
string str = new string('*', 8);
```

Comment: huh! I've never used that constructor!

Comment: Documentation can often come in handy ;-)

Answer (score 2):

My own quick workaround:

```
"".PadLeft(Password.Length,'*')
```

:)

But I guess it should be better solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
private static string WelcomeString = "wordsandstuff";
private static Int32 padInt = WelcomeString.Length;
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
  Console.WriteLine(WelcomeString);
  Console.WriteLine("".PadLeft(padInt, '='));
  Console.ReadKey();
}
```